# Sized deallocation in C++: What is the correct behaviour of the global operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size)

Tags: c++, memory, c++14, delete-operator

I'm not sure if I understood "sized deallocation" correctly in C++.
In C++14 the following signature [was added](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3778.html) to the global scope:

```
void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept
```

I'm using GCC 7.1.0 to compile the following source:

```
#include <cstdio>   // printf()
#include <cstdlib>  // exit(),malloc(),free()
#include <new>      // new(),delete()

void* operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    std::printf("-> operator ::new(std::size_t %zu)\n", size);
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::printf("-> operator ::delete(void* %p)\n", ptr);
    free(ptr);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept
{
    std::printf("-> operator ::delete(void* %p, size_t %zu)\n", ptr, size);
    free(ptr);
}


struct B
{
    double d1;
    void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        std::printf("-> operator B::new(std::size_t %zu)\n", size);
        return malloc(size);
    };

    void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size)
    {
        std::printf("-> operator B::delete(void* %p, size_t %zu)\n", ptr, size);
        free(ptr);
    };

    virtual ~B()
    {
        std::printf("-> B::~B()");
    }
};


struct D : public B
{
    double d2;
    virtual ~D()
    {
        std::printf("-> D::~D()");
    }
};

int main()
{

    B *b21 = new B();
    delete b21;

    B *b22 = new D();
    delete b22;

    D *d21 = new D();
    delete d21;

    std::printf("*****************************\n");

    B *b11 = ::new B();
    ::delete b11;

    B *b12 = ::new D();
    ::delete b12;

    D *d11 = ::new D();
    ::delete d11;

    return 0;
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 16)
-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 0x16e3010, size_t 16)
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 0x16e3010, size_t 24)
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 0x16e3010, size_t 24)
*****************************
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 16)
-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 0x16e3010, size_t 16)
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 0x16e3010, size_t 16)
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 0x16e3010, size_t 24)
```

MS Visual Studio 2017 gives me the following output:

```
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 16)
-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 0081CDE0, size_t 16)
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 00808868, size_t 24)
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 00808868, size_t 24)
*****************************
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 16)
-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 0081CDE0, size_t 16)
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 00808868, size_t 24)
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 00808868, size_t 24)
```

And Clang 5.0 does not even call the global sized deallocation `operator delete` (just the the `operator delete` with one parameter). As T.C. mentioned in the comment section Clang needs the additional parameter `-fsized-deallocation` to use sized allocation and the result will be the same as for GCC:

```
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 16)
-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 0x219b6c0, size_t 16)
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 0x219b6c0, size_t 24)
-> operator B::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator B::delete(void* 0x219b6c0, size_t 24)
*****************************
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 16)
-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 0x219b6c0, size_t 16)
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 0x219b6c0, size_t 16)
-> operator ::new(std::size_t 24)
-> D::~D()-> B::~B()-> operator ::delete(void* 0x219b6c0, size_t 24)
```

For me VS2017 seems to have the correct behaviour because my understanding of the class specific operator is to use the size of the derived class even if delete was called on a base class pointer.
I would expect a symmetrical behaviour by calling the global `operator delete`.

I've looked through the ISO C++11/14 standard but I don't think I've found any specific on how the global and class local operators should behave (that might be just me having problems to interpret the wording of the standard and because I'm not a native speaker).

Can someone elaborate on this topic?

What should be the correct behaviour?

Comment: Note that the compiler is not required to use the user provided `new` and `delete` (and/or not use `new` and `delete` at all) if it can prove that it doesn't change the semantics of the program.

Comment: Clang requires `-fsized-deallocation`, and then it agrees with GCC. However, looks like MSVC got it right here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the double-colon operator prefixing your `delete` operator is circumventing the “correct” `operator delete()`.  I have exercised the code on GCC, Clang, and Intel’s compiler, and they all agree that the `delete` operator should be sent a 16 byte size.  This is because they seem to be interpreting the C++ specification as saying that you have explicitly asked for the globally-scoped deletion function, ignoring any dynamic dispatch.  More on this later.

## What’s Happening

First, let’s tweak your original code a bit to eliminate some variables:

```cpp
struct B
{
    double d1;
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct D : public B
{
    double d2;
};

int main()
{
    B *b01 = new D();
    ::delete b01; // 1: The "problem" case.

    D *d01 = new D();
    ::delete d01; // 2: The "problem" case (sanity check).

    B *b02 = ::new D();
    delete b02;   // 3: Typical deletion.

    return 0;
}
```

Actually, none of the overrides are required to exhibit this behavior.  We can look at the emitted assembly to see what’s happening.  By default, GCC seems to use the sized `delete` operator, so the above is interesting (I compiled with GCC 11, `-O0`).  As you noticed, the compiler passes `sizeof(*b01)` to the deletion function:

```x86asm
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
    sub     rdx, 16
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx]
    lea     rbx, [rax+rdx]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    rdx
    mov     esi, 16  // Passed as the size to delete().
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
```

... essentially, look up the virtual destructor, invoke it, then call the delete function with the size of `*b01` (note: in the standard library case, this is probably fine, because the heap knows how large the allocation actually is, and will reap it fully).

To confirm that we’re looking for the size in the current scope, statically, I added example 2, which emits `sizeof(*d01)` into the second parameter:

```x86asm
    call    rdx
    mov     esi, 24  // Passed as the size to delete().
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
```

Where is really gets interesting is in the “normal” case, example 3:

```x86asm
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
    add     rdx, 8   // Offset 8 in the vtable for b02.
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    rdx
```

Here, it looks in the vtable for `b02`, and finds the “deleting destructor.”  This is a function that wraps what we typically think of as the destructor (since it’s on the vtable, we’re going to find it’s) for `D`, and calls the `delete` operator after this function executes.  E.g:

```x86asm
    // (Prolog omitted.)
    call    D::~D() // [complete object destructor]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     esi, 24
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
```

So we did a virtual lookup for the destructor, ran the correct one, then the `delete` operator gets a 24 byte size for it’s second parameter.

## Justification from the C++ Specification

If we take a look at the C++ (C++14, in this case) specification, §12.5.4 (Free store), it notes:

> Class-specific deallocation function lookup is a part of general deallocation function lookup (5.3.5) and occurs as follows.  If the *delete-expression* is used to deallocate a class object whose static type has a virtual destructor, the deallocation function is the one selected at the point of definition of the dynamic type’s virtual destructor (12.4).  Otherwise, if the *delete-expression* is used to deallocate an object of class `T` or array thereof, the static and dynamic types of the object shall be identical and the deallocation function’s name is looked up in the scope of `T`.  If this lookup fails to find the name, general deallocation function lookup (5.3.5) continues...

In other words (my interpretation is), when you defined a virtual destructor for `B`, you defined an implicit `operator delete`, but by invoking `::delete`, you essentially ask the compiler to ignore the *dynamic* type, and refer only to the *static* type in the current scope, which has a size of 16 bytes.  *You have selected a delete function, so there’s no need for the compiler to dynamically look one up.*

Again, in §5.3.5.9 (Delete):

> When the keyword `delete` in a *delete-expression* is preceded by the unary `::` operator, the deallocation function’s name is looked up in global scope.  Otherwise, the lookup considers class-specific deallocation functions (12.5).  If no class-specific deallocation function is found, the deallocation function’s name is looked up in global scope.

Another way of saying, “you asked for the global function, so I skipped the part where I look up the class-specific function.”

One could argue that the MSVC behavior is also valid, as through all this, there’s *nothing that explicitly states that the size passed to the delete function is inexorably tied to the function itself.*  Certainly, also, the MSVC behavior insulates the coder from having to navigate another mine in the Undefined Behavior minefield, as the compiler managed to grab the actual correct size from somewhere.  Looking at the emitted code from GCC, however, it would be “difficult” to gather the correct size, while explicitly calling the globally scoped delete function.